# VSIX LanguageService FindToolWindow(...) returns null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I have two VSIX packages (VS2010 SDK), one containing a LanguageService and one the ProjectPackage (based on Managed Package Framework for Projects) for my language. Now I need to establish some sort of communication channel where the LanguageService can retrieve additional information from the ProjectPackage. In the ProjectPackage, the information is available via a toolWindow, which can be retieved using

```
package.FindToolWindow(typeof(HierarchyViewerWindow), 0, false) as HierarchyViewerWindow;
```

The LanguageService inherits from the same Package base Class as the ProjectPackage, so I thought I could use the same mechanism here. The call returns `null` though.

So the basic question is whether I am doing something wrong or this is impossible for some reason... Or if there is a better way to establish communication between a LanguageService and another VSIX package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ProjectPackage can [Provide a Custom Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb164693.aspx) and your LanguageService can access it via the standard [GetService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165052.aspx) call.

Comment: Just what I was searching for. I guess that a toolwindow is always local to the package that created it?

Comment: Tool windows should be global. Make sure its type is global and it is already created when you search for it.